# Java Jlayer Mp3 Player - how to repeat and stop song

Tags: java, netbeans, mp3, jlayer

I have problem with mp 3 player. I'm using jLayer.
This is my code

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

new Thread (){
  public void run(){  
          try
{

Player prehravac;
 FileInputStream buff = new FileInputStream(Okno.filename);
            prehravac = new Player(buff);
            prehravac.play();
            if (prehravac != null)
            {
                prehravac.play();
            }
            }
catch(Exception e)
        {

        } 
         }

}.start();
 }
```

In my application I need to play song from the beginning to the end. So when song ends I need to start it again and when window closes I want to stop this song...

Answer (score 4):

JLayer does not support continuous play, so you have to use a loop to repeatedly start a new player after the old one finished. For example:

`try
        {
            do
            {
                FileInputStream buff = new FileInputStream(Okno.filename);
                prehravac = new AdvancedPlayer(buff );
                prehravac .play();
            }while(loop); 
        }
        catch(Exception ioe)
        {
            //TODO error handling
        }`

with loop being a boolean you can set true or false in a different method depending on if you want it to be played just once or repeatedly.

If you want to access the thread later you should at least declare it to a variable. Even better is writing a seperate class that extends thread. Doing so you can add method to the thread you can later call.

For your code it might look something like that:

```
import java.io.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;

public class MyAudioPlayer extends Thread {

    private String fileLocation;
    private boolean loop;
    private Player prehravac;

    public MyAudioPlayer(String fileLocation, boolean loop) {
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
        this.loop = loop;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            do {
                FileInputStream buff = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
                prehravac = new Player(buff);
                prehravac.play();
            } while (loop);
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            // TODO error handling
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        loop = false;
        prehravac.close();
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

With this you can simply create the Thread when and wherever you want like this:

```
private MyAudioPlayer thePlayer;

    [... some class code here...]

    public void yourMethod(){
        thePlayer = new MyAudioPlayer("path of the music file", true);
        thePlayer.start();
    }
```

and if you want to get rid of it at some point call `thePlayer.close();`
Note that thePlayer should be an instance variable so you can reuse it again. If you only declare it within a method it will disappear after the method is finished.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im sorry i didnt thank you. It really helped me thanks a lot :))