# Can't Loop MP3 File

Tags: java

Okay so I'm trying to get a sound file looped forever whilst the application is open. This is currently the piece of code I've got which runs the sound file.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Josh's 2D College Project");
        window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        try{

            File file = new File("C:/Users/Josh Scott (Zinotia)/Desktop/2D College Project/Resources/Sounds/BGSong.mp3");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            try{

                Player player = new Player(bis);
                player.play();

            } catch(JavaLayerException ex) {}

        } catch(IOException e){} 
    }
}
```

I'm using JavaZoom's JavaLayer in order to play the Mp3 file. Could anyone possibly give me another way to loop & use the sound file either with a different way or using the [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html).

Comment: Hello, please look at [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17032994/824495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an Listener to the player;

this can be done if you're using the **AdvancedPlayer** instead of the **Player** .

```
AdvancedPlayer p = new AdvancedPlayer(bis)
p.setPlayBackListener(new Playbacklistener(){

    //override unimplemented methods
    @Override
    public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent evt){
        p.start()
    }

    @Override
    public void playbackStarted(PlaybackEvent evt){}
};
```

NOTE - this are only fragments, you need to integrate it into your code...

Answer (score 1):

First, get how long the mp3 file exactly is. Then inside the second try statement add a `while(true)` and inside that add the

```
player.play();
```

and then add this

```
thread.Sleep(//mp3 length in milliseconds here)
```

It should look like this:

```
try {
     Player player = new Player(bis);
     while(true) {
        player.play();
        Thread.Sleep(69000); //length of mp3 here
     }
}
```

You could also try

```
try {
     Player player = new Player(bis);
     while(true) {
        player.play();
     }
}
```

But I am not sure if that would work or just keep playing the sound instantly over and over again.